# error:unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

[image: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>]

How to solve this error , should I backup the file and uninstall and install it again , if does, how ? any other solution provided , any help would be appreciated .Thanks

Comment: The file you showed is an XML file, apparently a layout resource XML file, not a Gradle build file.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; they're hard to read and when the links break, your question becomes pointless. Please [edit] your question and provide more details (a [mcve] would be best): what is the file that you are showing, what command triggers the problem? See [ask].

Comment: File->invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project(Build->Clean Project), than scynronise again the build.gradle file.